# How to update/insert timestamp value into a timestamp field in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to build small API. I am using Laravel.

I have this table for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `Incomes` (
    .......................................
    `comment` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dateInsert` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dateUpdate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dateDelete` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`guid`),
    .......................................
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I am doing updating of `dateUpdate` field on some row:

```
update `Incomes` set `dateInsert` = '1432111937' where `guid` = 'lalvlldlv1laslf'
```

After that I have this data in row: 
[image]

I don't even have timestamp there, just `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Why I get so?

Why question about PHP? I am using Laravel to update rows.

I have this code, which generates code above:

```
$jsonArray = $input->data;
foreach ($jsonArray as $item) {
    $item = (object)$item;
    $income = Income::find($item->guid);
    if($income) {
        $income->categoryId = $item->categoryId;
        $income->billId = $item->billId;
        $income->userId = $item->userId;
        $income->amount = $item->amount;
        $income->comment = $item->comment;
        $income->dateInsert = $item->dateInsert;
        $income->dateUpdate = $item->dateUpdate;
        $income->dateDelete = $item->dateDelete;
        $income->save();
    }
}
```

I parse this json into `$jsonArray` variable:

```
{
  "data": [
            {
                "guid": "lalvlldlv1laslf",
                "categoryId": "123e1cs",
                "billId": "12312",
                "userId": "214123",
                "amount": 200,
                "comment": null,
                "dateInsert": 1432111937,
                "dateUpdate": null,
                "dateDelete": null
            }
   ]
}
```

Why I am not getting normal date/normal timestamp in rows?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` column doesn't accept the integer, it accepts a formatted string which it internally converts to unix timestamp integer.

Answer (score 4):

`Timestamp` datatype supports date in `Y-m-d H-i-s` format and hence its failing, you need to convert into proper format. In mysql it could be done using `from_unixtime`

```
mysql> select from_unixtime('1432111937');
+-----------------------------+
| from_unixtime('1432111937') |
+-----------------------------+
| 2015-05-20 14:22:17         |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

So the update command will be

```
update `Incomes` 
set `dateInsert` = from_unixtime('1432111937')
where `guid` = 'lalvlldlv1laslf'
```

Comment: Ok, so my question should be converted to "How to wrap timestamps into `from_unixtime('...')`, right?

Comment: Thats fine with the question subject since many may not know about `from_unixtime`  function or may be `convert integer date value to mysql timestamp value`